# Withdraw and make a withdraw OR retreat and make a retreat

Tags: word-usage

Which one of the following sentences would be weird in English?

> - The enemy forces withdrew
> - The enemy forces made a withdrawal

I know we can say : "The enemy forces (retreated / made a retreat)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***The enemy forces withdrew*** somehow evokes the image of a bunch of guys bowing politely and leaving the ballroom. Don't ask me why.

***The enemy forces made a withdrawal*** evokes the image of the same bunch of guys fussing around an ATM.

***The enemy forces retreated*** sounds fine.

***The enemy forces beat a retreat*** sounds fine too.

***The enemy forces made a retreat*** is nonsense.

Comment: ["forces withdrew" is pretty common usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=forces+withdrew%2Cforces+withdraw&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cforces%20withdrew%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cforces%20withdraw%3B%2Cc0), though.  For example, "[When US forces withdrew from Iraq in 2011...](https://www.quora.com/When-US-forces-withdrew-from-Iraq-in-2011-why-did-the-Obama-administration-leave-Iraq-without-any-air-force)"  I agree that "made a withdrawal" sounds funny!

Comment: @stangdon: You mean, Iraq is _not_ one of the ballrooms at the Ritz? What was I thinking all these years ... Geez Louise ...